# Function Factory in R

Tags: r, functional-programming

I try to come up with a function factory by returning a dictionary of specialized functions, more or less like functional programming style.  I try to do this in the following code.

```
require(hash)

names = c("aa","bb","cc");
funs = hash()
for (i in seq(length(names))) {
  n = names[i]
  funs[[n]] = function(x) { 
    print(paste(n,":",x, sep="")) 
 }
}
```

Obviously, I have 3 functions in the array; however, they all behave the same as the last function in the iteration.

```
> funs[["aa"]](1)
[1] "cc:1"
> funs[["bb"]](2)
[1] "cc:2"
> funs[["cc"]](3)
[1] "cc:3"
```

My guess is that R didn't create new function instance but reuses the same function object inside the for-loop.

I try the following in hope that R will create different function object,

```
  funs[[n]] = eval(parse(text="function(x) { print(paste(n,':',x, sep='')) }"))
```

but it works the same as the first one.

Do you have an idea how to create a generator that creates different function objects?

Comment: I suspect this a lazy-evaluation issue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to Hadley's [Advanced R Programmin, Lexical scoping](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#lexical-scoping), the variable `n` in the body of functions `funs[['aa']]`, `funs[['bb']]`, and `funs[['cc']]` are the variable `n` in `<environment: R_GlobalEnv>`.

For example:

```
> funs[["aa"]](1)
[1] "cc:1"
> n <- "1234"
> funs[["aa"]]("1")
[1] "1234:1"
```

To do what you want, I'll write a function which returns a function:

```
funs.gen <- function(n) {
  force(n)
  function(x) {
    print(paste(n, ":", x, sep=""))
  }  
}

names = c("aa","bb","cc");
funs = hash()
for (i in seq(length(names))) {
  n = names[i]
  funs[[n]] = funs.gen(n)
}

funs[["aa"]](1)
funs[["bb"]](2)
funs[["cc"]](3)
```

Note that `force` is used to ask R not lazy evaluate expression `n`. If you remove it, then R will evaluate `n` out of the `for` loop which will produce the same result as your question.

Comment: It works!  Thank you for the advice and reference. Now I learnt that the function(){} inside the for-loop does create different function instances.  Using force() to have different values stick with the function together so that the function can be used independently.