# R, pass-by-value inside a function

Tags: r, reference, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

Suppose you define a function in R using the following code:

```
a <- 1
f <- function(x) x + a
```

If you latter redefine `a` you will change the function f.  (So, `f(1) = 2` as given but if you latter on redefine `a =2` then `f(1) = 3`.  Is there a way to force R to use the value of `a` at the time it compiles the function?  (That is, `f` would not change with latter redefinitions of `a`).

The above is the shortest case I could thought of that embodies the problem I am having.  More specifically, as requested, my situation is:

I am working with a bunch of objects I am calling "person".  Each person is defined as a probability distribution that depends on a n dimensional vector $a$  and a n dimensional vector of constrains w (the share of wealth).

I want to create a "society" with N people, that is a list of N persons.  To that end, I created two n by N matrices A and W.  I now loop over 1 to N to create the individuals.

```
Society <- list()

### doesn't evaluate theta at the time, but does w...
for (i in 1:Npeople) {
   w <- WealthDist[i,]
   u <- function(x)  prod(x^A[i,]) 

   P <- list(u,w)
   names(P) <- c("objective","w")
   Society[[length(Society)+1]] <- P

}
```

w gets is pass-by-value, so each person gets the right amount of wealth.  But A is pass-by-reference -- everybody is being assigned the same function u (namely, the function using i = N)

To finish it up, the next steps are to get the Society and, via two optimizations get an "equilibrium point".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a function which uses a locked binding and creates a function to complete your purpose. The former value of a will be used for `w` which will be stored in the environment of the function and will not be replaced by further values changes of `a`.

```
a <- 1
j <- new.env() # create a new environment
create.func <- function () {
  j$w <<- a
  function (x) {
    x+ j$w
  }
}
f <- create.func() 
a <- 2
f(2)
[1] 3 # if w was changed this should be 4
```

*Credits to Andrew Taylor (see comments)*

**EDIT:** BE CAREFUL: f will change if you call `create.func`, even if you do not store it into f. To avoid this, you could write this code (it clearly depends on what you want).

```
a <- 1
create.func <- function (x) {
  j <- new.env()
  j$w <- a
  function (x) {
    x + j$w
  }
}
f <- create.func()
f(1)
[1] 2
a <- 2
q <- create.func()
q(1)
[1] 3
f(1)
[1] 2
```

**EDIT 2:** Lazy evaluation doesn't apply here because a is evaluated by being set to `j$w`. If you had used it as an argument say:

```
function(a)
   function(x)
     #use a here
```

you would have to use `force` before defining the second function, because then it wouldn't be evaluated.

**EDIT 3:** I removed the `foo <-` etc. The function will return as soon as it is declared, since you want it to be similar to the code factories defined in your link.

**EDIT by OP**Just to add to the accepted answer that in spirit of 
[Function Factory in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19749923/function-factory-in-r)
the code below works:

```
funs.gen <- function(n) {
  force(n)
  function(x) {
    x + n
  }  
}

funs = list()
for (i in seq(length(names))) {
   n = names[i]
   funs[[n]] = funs.gen(i)
}
```

Comment: Of course if `w` then get's re-assigned, we've got a problem. Not so much solving the problem as putting it in the corner where no one will probably notice.

Comment: The problem statement made me believe (and I still believe so) that the function only wants a value of a when it is defined. If the OP redefines the function, this means they want a new value of a and so on. w can get changed only by calling `create.func` again, in other word in his problem this would be equivalent to *redefining the function*.

Comment: By simple re-assigning within the global environment `w` can be changed. Not only when calling `create.func`. `f(1);w<-2222;f(1)` give two separate answers. This is being a bit ridiculous on my part, since your solution clearly is the answer to the problem. I was thinking reassignment to a specific environment `j<-new.env();j$w<-a` would protect against this type of issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems to be working - I was running your code (and the one you post before).  I thought there would be some simple command in R that would do the trick (eval, force, or something like this).  But I guess that it is not so simple to do this in R.  I would vote and tick your answer if I had enough rep.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my answer a bit just now, `create.func` obviously needs not arguments and that was stupid of me. Please note that if you call `create.func` for an another variable again,  `f` will change too, although it will seem it shouldn't be done so. If this not the behaviour you'd like, please let me know

Comment: @JJO: You may not have enough reputation to upvote, but you can always mark an answer as accepted regardless of your reputation.

Comment: Utr, I've added both versions of the code. The first always changes f through calls of `create.func`, the second doesn't change its functionality.

Comment: @naltipar Say you want to create a list of 1000 functions such that the first function is addition by 1, the second function is addition by 2, ..., the last function is addition by 1000.  Would your code make it possible to build all such function via a for loop?  I am checking 

Maybe 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19749923/function-factory-in-r

is also in the same line?

http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html

is it in line with how you are solving the problem?

Comment: The second version will work, I've edited my answer and added some explanations. I hope I have fully covered you.

Answer (score 2):

R doesn't do pass by reference; everything is passed to functions by value. As you've noticed, since `a` is defined in the global environment, functions which reference `a` are referencing the global value of `a`, which is subject to change. To ensure that a specific value of `a` is used, you can use it as a parameter in the function.

```
f <- function(x, a = 1) {
    x + a
}
```

This defines `a` as a parameter that defaults to 1. The value of `a` used by the function will then always be the value passed to the function, regardless of whether `a` is defined in the global environment.

If you're going to use `lapply()`, you simply pass `a` as a parameter to `lapply()`.

```
lapply(X, f, a = <value>)
```

Comment: Thank you - i was hopping to avoid adding a new argument to the function (if I try to find zeros of the function, for example, I would have to let R know that I am fixing a at a given value -- since I am working with a list, I will use lapply and I am not sure if I would know how to inform R to use the right parameter a in lapply).

Comment: @JJO: This is still quite simple with `lapply()` since it honors further parameters passed to the input function. See my addition to the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Alex.  I think you are right, maybe I should bypass building a "Society" and just use a buch of lapply to the W and A matrices  - will try to rethink the code in this direction.  If it works, it surely would be the fastest option.

Comment: @JJO: I'm not sure what you mean by a "society," but if this answer sufficiently addresses your question, you can mark it as accepted. (Or one of the other answers--whichever works best for you.)

Comment: Hi Alex, I don't have enough rep to vote up or accept.  I am still trying to figure out how to best do the problem - it seems that the issue is related to "factory functions" in R.

Answer (score 1):

Define `a` within `f`

```
f <- function(x) {a<-1;x + a}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  It wouldn't work in my case since I am looping over a (I am creating a list of functions that depend on a parameter a - so, I cannot redefine a inside the function f)

Comment: Can you provide a more representative example in your post then, so we can provide an appropriate solution. Thanks

Comment: @JJO so you *want* this behavior? this has always struck me as a "gotcha" in r. you should be explicit about passing variables to functions